# Getting PlacementTarget of a ToolTip in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, tooltip

As [this MSDN page suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltip.placementtarget) you should be able to use data binding to set a placement target on a tooltip.

In my UWP app I have the following XAML and code behind:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyButton}"
                 Loaded="FunkyMethod">
            <Border Width="150"
                    Height="50"
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    Background="DeepSkyBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="This is a tooltip"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="White"/>
            </Border>
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>

    <Button.Content>Button with ToolTip</Button.Content>
</Button>
```

```cs
private void FunkyMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tooltip = sender as ToolTip;
    var button = tooltip?.PlacementTarget as Button; // always returns NULL for the placement target

    if (tooltip != null && button != null)
    {
        // do something funcky here.
    }
}
```

But the placement target never gets set and I always get NULL. Does anyone know why?

For context, I am trying to write code that would compute the horizontal/vertical offset needed to place a tooltip to the right of its parent and vertically centered. Something like this:

[image]

But I haven't been able to find a way of achieving this (Placement=Right or Top didn't work). So What I'm trying to do is to do it in code behind at runtime, by a) set Placement=Mouse, b) figure out the parent control via PlacementTarget, c) find out the mouse position relative to the parent control, d) compute the horizontal/vertical offset and set it for the tooltip

Comment: Who downvoted and voted to close this? This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still haven't heard back from Microsoft on this. As Justin XL pointed out x:Bind would work cleanly in some scenarios. But I was able to find a workaround that works for my scenarios. Here are the snippets:

```xml
<Style x:Key="ToolTipStyle1"
        TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Placement"
            Value="Mouse" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                      MaxWidth="300"
                      MinHeight="36"
                      MaxHeight="300">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Polygon Fill="#FF1589EE"
                             Width="10"
                             Height="12"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Points="0,6 10,0 10,12" />

                    <Border Grid.Column="1"
                            Background="#FF1589EE">
                        <TextBlock Margin="20,5,5,5"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   FontSize="16"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Border>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Button Width="150"
        Height="100"
        PointerMoved="MyButton_OnPointerMoved"
        PointerExited="MyButton_OnPointerExited"
        Content="Parent Control">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Loaded="MyToolTip_OnLoaded"
                    Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle1}"
                    Content="This is a tooltip" />
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private PointerPoint _devicePointer;
    private FrameworkElement _elementContainingDevicePointer;
    private void MyButton_OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _elementContainingDevicePointer = sender as FrameworkElement;
        _devicePointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(_elementContainingDevicePointer);
    }

    private void MyButton_OnPointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _devicePointer = null;
        _elementContainingDevicePointer = null;
    }

    private void MyToolTip_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tooltip = sender as ToolTip;

        if (_devicePointer != null && _elementContainingDevicePointer != null && tooltip != null)
        {
            var x = _elementContainingDevicePointer.ActualWidth - Math.Max(0, _devicePointer.Position.X);
            var y = _elementContainingDevicePointer.ActualHeight / 2 - Math.Max(0, _devicePointer.Position.Y) - tooltip.ActualHeight / 2;

            tooltip.HorizontalOffset = x + 5;
            tooltip.VerticalOffset = y - 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the traditional binding to `PlacementTarget="{x:Bind MyButton}"`. Note the default `Mode` of this is `OneTime` but I think it's OK for your case.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Don't understand why the traditional binding didn't work but this unblocks me so thanks.

Comment: @MeisamSeyedAliroteh this could well be a bug. :)

Comment: so the x:Bind approach would not work if I'm using a data template for my control and the tooltip is define inside that data template. Any ideas on how to work around that problem?

I'm building a menu for my app, essentially using a SplitView to host a ListView with ItemSource and ItemTemplate, and each item would have a tooltip so I need to define the tooltip and its host in a data template.

If traditional binding was working then this issue would have been solved.

Comment: Hmm... How about setting the `PlacementTarget` in code behind?

Comment: Yeah that would not be a very neat approach. Since the items in the ListView are generated from ItemsSource at runtime and since the data for the ItemSource is dynamic and changes depending on which server the user logs into and hence getting different menu items, trying to do this in code would mean jumping through hoops and getting something even more hacky done. I asked this question on the MS forum for UWP app developments hoping that someone from MS would reply as to why the Binding is not working the way their MSDN pages say it should.